# Set the font size in pycharm's python console or terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, fonts, pycharm

There are terminal and python console in pycharm, which are very convenient. But I found that the font size was too small to recognize in terminal or python console. How can change the font size in the terminal or python console?

Comment: You should ask this question in [PyCharm forum](http://forum.jetbrains.com/forum/PyCharm) not in SO.

Comment: Have you tried to search manual? I was able to find answer in official manual in 15 seconds.

Comment: It's not the font in editor.

Comment: I tried that. But this operation didn't change the font size in console. I also can change the font size of the tool bar. But they aren't the thing I expect.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I ask the question in wrong place. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Alot of people seem to think the answer is obvious.  I agree with the OP that it is not.  The most commonly referred link here does not say anything about the terminal.  If anyone is wondering about this, I found that when I reset the console font, the terminal did not change.  But then I closed and re-opened pycharm, and the terminal then had the font I wanted.

Answer (score 77):

In PyCharm 2016.3, the console font setting is squirrelled away under **Settings** > **Editor** > **Colors & Fonts** > **Console Font**:

[image: Console font settings in PyCharm]

**Note:** Changes to the colors and font are **not visible immediately**, you have to **restart the terminal session to apply them**. It's not enough to just hide and reopen the terminal. Just click the red cross button on the terminal's toolbar (*Close Terminal Session*) and reopen it. The same is valid also for the *Python Console*.

Comment: Note that in the more recent version Colors&Fonts was renamed to "Color Scheme"

Comment: but this doesn't affect the terminal font. Anything else to be done for that.

Comment: It affects the font in the terminal. And you **don't need to restart Pycharm** to apply the changes. Just *close the already opened terminal* (not just hide using the button in the top right corner of the terminal but using the red X button _Close session_ on the left side) *and reopen it* and new settings will be applied to it.

Comment: @imsrgadich Just reopen the terminal session as I described in the previous comment.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy yes realised that. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The location of console font changed in the latest versions of Pycharm.
**Settings** -> **Editor** -> **Color Scheme** -> **Console Font**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to File\Settings\Editor\Color & Fonts and choose save as  to save currently used schema by a new name in order to make changes on a new schema. Then in mentioned direction go to console font and  set size.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it doesn't work for me either but the problem was that:

you have to **close all terminal windows** to see the spacing effect.

Answer (score -2):

A simple google search would have lead you [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html).

You just need to create a personal scheme under settings >Editor > color and fonts.

**Edit**:Here this further explanation may help more.

1.In color and fonts choose save as and give a scheme name.

2.Go to console font and change size and primary font, which will be inaccessible if you didn't choose the personal scheme you created earlier.

Comment: I can do that. But I said that I wanted to change the font in pycharm's console.

Comment: Here added some more explanation, i hope this is what you were looking for, to change the font of the console that comes with pycharm.

Comment: My Google search of "pycharm console font size" did not have your reference on its first page - not so simple huh?