# PyCharm Console Font changes font only on Python Terminal

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using a 4k Windows laptop and I configured the compatibily settings for PyCharm(2017.2.3 Community Edition) and the font size of the editor looks fine.

Subsequently,I wanted to fix the font size of the terminal and the python console. Using this [post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/203465844-How-to-change-font-size-and-color-in-the-embedded-terminal-) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412739/set-the-font-size-in-pycharms-python-console-or-terminal) from stackoverflow, I went to *File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors Scheme -> Console Font* and I changed the font size. This resulted in changing the font size of only the python console and not the terminal. Any suggestion?

Pictures attached:
[image: Settings][image: Python Console][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to unistall it and install it again from the beginning without importing the settings. Should have a been a problem with the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to to go to do this? *"Settings" -> "Appearance and Behavior" -> "Appearance" -> Deactivate Override of default fonts*?

[Source](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000171344-Problems-with-4k-Monitor-after-new-update-of-Pycharm-and-WebStorm)