# How to change the font of Run terminal on Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I work with some Persian text files and when I run PyCharm it shows the result like this:

[image]

As you see, it's not easy to read. How can I change that font?

Comment: what you actually want to do

Comment: you want to extract the persian text from the image and convert it into desired language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to File > Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font.

Tick "Use console font instead of the default"
Choose font and size as you like.

Also follow:
[Set the font size in pycharm's python console or terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34412739/set-the-font-size-in-pycharms-python-console-or-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import hazm
import json
import requests
import urllib
from translate import translator

text = "persian"

quoted = urllib.quote_plus(text.encode("utf-8"))
print translator('fa','en',quoted)
```